# How to get the closest value from map by given key in scala?

Tags: scala, dictionary

For example, I have a `Map[Integer,String]` like

```
val map = Map(1 -> "a", 2 -> "b", 3 -> "c", 5 -> "d", 9 -> "e", 100 -> "z")
```

- If given key is 2, then "b" is expected to return.
- If given key is 50, then "e" and "z" are expected to return.
- If given key is 0, then "a" is expected to return.

In other words, if the key exists in the `Map` the corresponding value should be returned. Otherwise the values of the closest smaller and larger keys should be returned (in the case no other key is smaller only the value of the closest larger key should be returned and vice versa).

How can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Map` doesn't preserve order hence I would suggest creating a method that:

1. converts the `Map` into a `TreeMap`
2. generates the lower/upper Map entries as Options in a list using `to(key).lastOption` and `from(key).headOption`, respectively
3. flattens the list and extracts the Map values:

Sample code as follows:

```
val map = Map(1->"a", 2->"b", 100->"z", 9->"e", 3->"c", 5->"d")

def closestValues(m: Map[Int, String], key: Int): Seq[String] = {
  import scala.collection.immutable.TreeMap
  val tm = TreeMap(m.toSeq: _*)

  Seq( tm.to(key).lastOption, tm.from(key).headOption ).
    flatten.distinct.map{ case (k, v) => v }
}

closestValues(map, 0)
// res1: Seq[String] = List(a)

closestValues(map, 2)
// res2: Seq[String] = List(b)

closestValues(map, 50)
// res3: Seq[String] = List(e, z)

closestValues(map, 101)
// res4: Seq[String] = List(z)
```

---

**UPDATE**:

Starting Scala `2.13`, methods `to` and `from` for `TreeMap` are replaced with `rangeTo` and `rangeFrom`, respectively.

Comment: Nicely done. I'd move the `distinct` before the `map(_._2)` call, just in case the near-below key and the near-above key happen to reference identical values.

Comment: Good catch.  Thanks @jwvh.  I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

My 2-cents worth.

```
def getClose[K](m: Map[Int,K], k: Int): Seq[K] =
  if (m.get(k).nonEmpty) Seq(m(k))
  else {
    val (below,above) = m.keys.partition(_ < k)
    Seq( if (below.isEmpty) None else Some(below.max)
       , if (above.isEmpty) None else Some(above.min)
       ).flatten.map(m)
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend first converting the `Map` to a `SortedMap` since the order of the keys needs to be taken into account.

```
val map = Map(1->"a",2->"b",3->"c",5->"d",9->"e",100->"z")
val sortedMap = SortedMap[Int, String]() ++ map
```

After that, use the following method to get the closest values. The result is returned as a List.

```
def getClosestValue(num: Int) = {
  if (sortedMap.contains(num)) {
    List(sortedMap(num))
  } else {
    lazy val larger = sortedMap.filterKeys(_ > num)
    lazy val lower  = sortedMap.filterKeys(_ < num)
    if (larger.isEmpty) {
      List(sortedMap.last._2)
    } else if (lower.isEmpty) {
      List(sortedMap.head._2)
    } else {
      List(lower.last._2, larger.head._2)
    }
  }
}
```

Testing it with the following values:

```
println(getClosestValue(2))
println(getClosestValue(50))
println(getClosestValue(0))
println(getClosestValue(101))
```

will give

```
List(b)
List(z, e)
List(a)
List(z)
```

Answer (score 0):

This not an efficient solution but you can do something like below

```
val map =Map(1->"a",2->"b",3->"c",5->"d",9->"e",100->"z")

val keyset = map.keySet

def getNearestValues(key: Int) : Array[String] = {
  if(keyset.contains(key)) Array(map(key))
  else{
    var array = Array.empty[String]
    val less = keyset.filter(_ < key)
    if(!less.isEmpty) array = array ++ Array(map(less.toList.sortWith(_ < _).last))
    val greater = keyset.filter(_ > key)
    if(!greater.isEmpty) array = array ++ Array(map(greater.toList.sortWith(_ < _).head))
    array
  }
}
```

**A small bit of functional way**

```
val map =Map(1->"a",2->"b",3->"c",5->"d",9->"e",100->"z")

val keyset = map.keySet

def getNearestValues(key: Int) : Array[String] = keyset.contains(key) match {
  case true => Array(map(key))
  case false => {
    val (lower, upper) = keyset.toList.sortWith(_ < _).span(x => x < key)
    val lowArray = if(lower.isEmpty) Array.empty[String] else Array(map(lower.last))
    val upperArray = if(upper.isEmpty) Array.empty[String] else Array(map(upper.head))
    lowArray ++ upperArray
  }
}
```

`getNearestValues(0)` should return `Array(a)` and `getNearestValues(50)` should return `Array(e, z)` and `getNearestValues(9)` should return `Array(e)`

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem with the complexity smaller that in any proposed solutions above . So, if performance is critical, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57667319/11843739).

Answer (score 0):

Another Scala solution

```
val m = Map(1 -> "a", 2 -> "b", 3 -> "c", 5 -> "d", 9 -> "e", 100 -> "z")

  List(0, 2, 50, 101).foreach { i => {
    val inp = i
    val (mn, mx) = if (m.get(inp).nonEmpty) (Map(inp -> m(inp)), Map(inp -> m(inp))) else m.partition(x => x._1 > inp)
    (mn, mx) match {
      case (x, y) if y.isEmpty => println(m(mn.keys.min))
      case (x, y) if x.isEmpty => println(m(mx.keys.max))
      case (x, y) if y == x => println(m(inp))
      case (x, y) => println(m(mn.keys.min), m(mx.keys.max))
    }

  }

  }
```

Results:

```
a
b
(z,e)
z
```